# Classification of singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

This is from Ahlfors' complex analysis:

For a more detailed discussion of isolated singularities, we consider the
conditions (1) $\lim_{z \to a} |z - a|^\alpha |f(z)| = 0$, (2) $\lim_{z \to a} |z - a|^{\alpha} |f(z)| = \infty$, for
real values of $\alpha$. If (1) hold for a certain $\alpha$, then it holds for all larger $\alpha$, and
hence for some integer $m$. Then $(z - a)^m f(z)$ has a removable singularity and
vanishes for $z = a$. Either $f(z)$ is identically zero, in which case (1) holds for
all $\alpha$, or $(z - a)^m f(z)$ has a zero of finite order $k$. In the latter case it
follows at once that (1) holds for all $\alpha > h = m - k$, while (2) holds
for all $\alpha < h$.

I don't understand why $(z - a)^m f(z)$ has a removable singularity at z=a, and also in the latter case, $(z - a)^m f(z)$ has a zero of finite order k. Doesn't has a removable singularity at z=a mean $(z - a)^m f(z)$ is undefined at a, then how can z=a is also a zero (which means f(a)=0 and then f is defined at a)?

Comment: It doesn't say that $(z-a)^{m}f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$ but at $z=a$

Comment: @DanyWose yes at a, it's a typo, edited